# Get video ID from a YouTube playlist

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

I need to get the Video Ids from a YouTube Playlist.

e.g.: Thats our demo playlist: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8B03F998924DA45B

That's my c# code:

```
SyndicationFeed feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL8B03F998924DA45B?v=2");
```

I then can not find the IDs of the single videos from the playlist in my `feed` object. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Data API v3](http://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/). Data API is the one that reflects playlists in YouTube and highly supported.

In v3, you will do a [playlistItems->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) call with setting the [playlistId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#playlistId).

In the response, if the playlist item is a video, you can get videoId from either [snippet.resourceId.videoId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#snippet.resourceId.videoId) or [contentDetails.videoId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#contentDetails.videoId)

You can find [C# examples here](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-dotnet).