# Script which lists every video title in a YouTube playlist?

Tags: youtube, playlist

This is my first question on this forum. I am a complete beginner to code/scripting/programming, so forgive me if I'm being naive. I am an architecture student + DJ and I think learning to code will be useful for my career.

Over my life I've created hundreds of youtube playlists with 10000s of songs/videos. About 90 percent of the music I listen to is not available to buy so I use Soulseek to download lossless files (wav, flac) to play out.. or at the least MP3. Mostly rare, underground music.

1. The first thing I need is a script which lists the title of every video in a chosen playlist into a notebook/excel file. This is a useful exercise in its own right as I'd like the names in case YT decides to delete playlists or music. (To include the channel would be a bonus.) Example:

Lani Hall - Love Song

Scribble - Mother Of Pearl

Robertinho De Recife - Só Pra Você Ver (Brazil, 1981)
...

2. Going forward I want to use the list to create an automated search + download via Soulseek for the first result (if any) for each title.

There are definitely some intricacies with this process such as cluttered titles, for example: *"EPSILON "Wake Up" 1975 Funk Disco"*. When the search should ideally be *Epsilon - Wake Up*. I can probably go through and sort out the crap afterwards, but I really just want to know if this is possible in the first instance.

Some related threads:

[Python Script to create a list of video titles of a YouTube playlist containing more than 100 videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55992902/python-script-to-create-a-list-of-video-titles-of-a-youtube-playlist-containing)

[Get video ID from a YouTube playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694568/get-video-id-from-a-youtube-playlist)

[Get Youtube playlist by Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886934/get-youtube-playlist-by-title)

[Get titles from playlist videos in YouTube iframe API (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979372/get-titles-from-playlist-videos-in-youtube-iframe-api-javascript)

[how to get youtube playlist video id with video title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201248/how-to-get-youtube-playlist-video-id-with-video-title)

Comment: Yes, It is absolutely possible, just go ahead.